# El significado de "yuuuju"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Alquilen escribió lo siguiente en línea:

"Nada más que venga Juan, nos vamos todos al tobogán (yuuuju)."

¿Qué significa "yuuuju" en este contexto? Muchas gracias

Comment: Es una expresión de júbilo.

Answer (score 3):

Se trata de una [**interjección**](https://dle.rae.es/interjecci%C3%B3n). Las interjecciones son palabras que se usan para *manifiestar impresiones, verbalizar sentimientos o realizar actos de habla apelativos*.

El DLE no recoge **yuju** pero sí otra palabra de sonido muy parecido que puede emplearse en su lugar: [**yupi**](https://dle.rae.es/yupi?m=form)

> **yupi**
>
> 1. interj. U. para expresar júbilo.

Por si te resulta de utilidad, creo que el equivalente en inglés sería **yahoo**, también de sonido muy similar. Si la consultamos en el Diccionario Oxford obtenemos que

> **yahoo**
>  EXCLAMATION Expressing great joy or excitement.
>
> *‘yahoo—my plan worked!’*

expresar júbilo (ES) = expressing joy (EN)
yuju (ES) = yupi (ES) = yahoo (EN)

Answer (score 1):

La palabra "yuuuju" significa o representa el sonido que hace el/los niños al saber que se van a poder tirar por el tobogan, al ser una accion divertida los niños estan contentos y lo demuestran con esta palabra.